# How to form the Query string in web address url in Angular state router by using state go method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have a product list page, there have list of products,when click the particular products, call the function and in the function state.go.

**Not working in dynamic:**

$state.go('home.product.detail', { 
'productID': "redminote4", 'brand': 'x', "store":"amazon" });

```
.state('home.product.detail', {
    url: '/products/:?productID?brand?store',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: baseUrl + 'products/products',
            controller: 'productsController'
        }
    },
    data: {
        displayName: '',
        displayImg: 'Images/productsHeaderIcon.png'
    }, resolve: {

        param2: function (LoginHome) {

            return LoginHome.getHomeService1();

        }
    }
```

**

```
Output  weburl need to be:
productID=redminote4&brand=amazon&store=amazon:
```

other thing is value is getting in stateparams:
eg) stateparams.productId=redminote but url not constructed
**

working fine:

when i set the value in param i am getting the outputurl mentioned in above:

```
**function call:**

$state.go('home.product.detail', { 
'productID': "redminote4", 'brand': 'x', "store":"amazon" });
```

App:

```
 .state('home.product.detail', {
  url: '/products/:?productID?brand?store',
params:{
'productID': "redminote4", 
'brand': 'x', 
"store":"amazon" }

},
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: baseUrl + 'products/products',
                controller: 'productsController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            displayName: '',
            displayImg: 'Images/productsHeaderIcon.png'
        }, resolve: {

            param2: function (LoginHome) {

                return LoginHome.getHomeService1();

            }
        }
```

why the url not formed in dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

The way the parameters are defined in your url is incorrect. Anyway, one option is to use the lifecycle methods and return a target

```
.state('home.product.detail', {
    url: '/products/?productID&?brand&?store',
    params:{
        'productID': {
            value: "redminote4", 
            squash: true
        }
        'brand': {
            value: "x", 
            squash: true
        }, 
        'store': {
            value: "amazon", 
            squash: true
        }
},
data: {
    displayName: '',
    displayImg: 'Images/productsHeaderIcon.png'
},
onEnter: ['$transition$', '$state$', 'LoginHome', function(transition, state, LoginHome){

    if(!transition.options().resolvedParams){
       return transition.router.stateService.target(
                 transition.to().name, 
                 {
                    productID: 'redminote4', 
                    brand: 'x', 
                    store:'amazon'
                 },
                 { 
                    resolvedParams: true 
                 }
           );
        }
    }]
```

This interrupts the state change and replaces it with your new target which now is populated with your parameters and has a custom key in the options object that I'm using in this example to not redirect the state change again.

You can learn more about the lifecycle [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#to) and the TargetState we return [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/state.targetstate.html)